# Can I display "bold" characters instead of "intense/bright" in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

I want to display bold characters in WSL through [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) (currently using ConEmu 190331 x64).

When I print the following `echo -e "FROM NOT BOLD \e[1mTO BOLD\e[0m"`, I get this [Image to ConEmu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PkIl.png)

As you can see, ConEmu uses the intensity/brightness to represent bold.
I would like to be able to switch that to actually use bold instead just like in [WSLTTY](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty) (MinTTY for WSL): [Image to  WSLTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdfMX.png)

Is it possible? I couldn't find instructions in ConEmu's manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows console API does not provide enough attributes to represent *boldness*. That's why *bold* attributes may be (yet) set only at the bottom of the buffer ([current implementation](https://conemu.github.io/en/Xterm256Colors.html)) where xterm256 and true-color works.

Than, you may use `\e[1m` to set bold attribute when you set brightness explicitly (e.g. `\e[90m`) or xterm color from 256 palette (e.g. `\e[38;5;7m`).

[image]

Comment: Ok, I get it. I found this thread on the [Microsoft Windows Console GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/109) that says it has been in their to do list ... since 2017.

Would it be conceivable to have an option inside ConEmu that would allow to choose the rendering either bright and bold for `\e[1m` or is that out of ConEmu's control? In other word, overwrite the brightness sent by the Windows Console to be displayed as bold.

Comment: It's under ConEmu control. I don't remember if there is already created feature request on GitHub. If there is no such request, you may create yours ;)

Comment: Thank you, I just opened a feature request: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1896